# Print status from DynamicReport(Print Dialog) Java

Tags: java, jasper-reports, dynamic-reports

I am using DynamicReport 4.0 and using the following code to print the generated report. But I am unable to get the status of print dialog from it because its returns JasperReportBuilder object.

```
JasperReportBuilder report = DynamicReports.report();
...
...
...
report.print();
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply if you want to see print dialog change report.print(); into report.print(true);